# Toggle validation hide(+) when other in open(-) SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am developing a "Dashboard Report" in SSRS Visual Studio 2010. I Am trying to put 8 charts graphs at the same location. Each chart must open from each textbox I assigned a toggle. Each chart has the visibility as Hidden and display by textbox name.

Now I am trying to make a validation which determine that only one chart must show at the time. Because when I try to see an individual chart always I have to close which was open before.

I have created a parameter to assign an InitialToggleState Expression, but I haven't succeed.

I will appreciated any good suggestion step by step. Thanks

Comment: Can you include an image of the layout you have presently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a Hidden parameter to control which chart is open?  By defining one you can use the textboxes to control an identifier for which chart you wish to display.

**Method**

1. First define a Hidden Pameter by creating a new parameter and setting the visibility to ‘Hidden’.  I have created one called `OpenChart`
2. Create your charts (you have probably already done this by the looks of things.  Set each charts visibility to be equivalent to

   ```
   =iif(Parameters!OpenChart.Value = 1, false, true)
   ```

   Changing the value ‘1’ to a unique number for each chart
3. Create your control buttons, possibly using text boxes.  Create as many buttons as there are charts to disaply (you’ve probably done this already too).  For each button Set the action to be a reloading of this report, using the same existing parameters, but with the OpenCahrt Parameter set to the chart identifier set in 2. Above

   [image]
4. The report now looks like this (for 3 buttons)

   [image]

**Result**

When the report is run and the ‘One’ textbox is clicked the output looks like this

[image]

And for 'Two' like this

[image]

And so on...

You don’t have to put the charts side by side of course, they can be layered on top of each other.  I only laid them out like this for clarity.

Hopefully this will help save you from trying to validate all the charts are closed before the next one is open, because only one can be open at a time.

Please let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would like to know how the chart knows from which button (textbox) is coming from the action?

Comment: In my example above you set **each text box** to trigger a reload of the report with a **specific identifier** for `OpenChart` (step 3).  When the report renders each chart runs the calculation for visibility, and only the one with the value for `OpenChart` is set to true.  Therefore all others are hidden.

Comment: Thank you So much @jonnus I have tried it and it works perfectly. Is there any validation to bring my chart from its position to the top? Because I have layered on top of each other, but some how they are putting the layout like growing and affecting other items positions into my report. I would like they keep their own position and same size without affect GUI.

Comment: Can you include an image of your current layout as when I layer the charts they all appear in the same space, with no other items in the report moving around...

Comment: Sorry, for some reasons I cannot send you an image of this issued.

Let's say that according to your charts images. the one which is named **one** has the same Position:**location** than **Chart_two** and **Chart_three** and after I create the parameter OpenChart the items I have below the charts are moving with a big white space in between. Also I have those charts in front of Textbox which is hiden and is only specifying the space I would like to put those charts permanently.

Comment: Unfortunately i can;t recreate the problem.  Which version of SSRS BIDS/SSDT are you using?  2008? 2010? 2013?

Comment: SSRS Visual studio 2010. Also I have **ConsumerConteinerWhitespace** = **true** and the textbox which is hidden has **Cangrow**= **false**. Is there any weird charts behavior which I am missing?

Comment: Not that I can think of, no.  I developed the above in VS2008 so I can't recreate exactly your setup, but I doubt behaviour such as this should have changed between versions...